# Does Google Analytics track localhost activity?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to know if Google Analytics is tracking my localhost activity.

We have the below GA tracking script on each page and are developing new features on our local machines. Is Google tracking our visits, sessions, and goal conversions?

Tracking Script

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-9', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Goal Conversion Script

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load',function(){
      jQuery('.happy-form')
          .submit(function(){
              ga('send', 'event','subscribe','clickSubmit','happyPlace');
          });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked in your real time stats?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will have to test this out with Goals.. (that is my main concern)

Comment: Real time data is unfiltered, so it's good for testing goals and events

Comment: @HowardE, wanted to mention that filters ARE indeed applied in RT reports. The only time RT data is unfiltered is if you don't have filters for that particular view.

Comment: Check if any of browser plugins is blocking. Open the browser in incognito mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Admin in Google Analytics, in the third column click on Filters.

Add a filter that only includes the hostname you do want to track, that way anything else, include localhost, will be excluded from your data going forward.

It's not possible to correct data that has already been gathered.

Comment: Filters cannot be applied to Google Analytics 4 Properties.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that to track on localhost, you could also set your trackers cookie domain to `none` (`auto` works,  too, cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#automatic_cookie_domain_configuration). Install GA Debugger for Chrome to make sure the hits are sent and also to see valuable debugging info.

Edit (based on comment): I'm not sure how to prevent tracking in localhost, but if you do the converse of the above, and set your cookie domain to your top level domain (ie. example.com), then that shouldn't track your localhost.

Comment: I am trying to avoid being tracked in localhost

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was happening to me.
You need to write a conditional statement in your code to only show the analytics tag when you are on the live website.

For example, in javascript this would look like;

```
<script>
var host = window.location.hostname;
if(host == "example.com")
{
    // your google analytic code here
}
</script>
```

Or you could also write it like below, in order to show on any site that is NOT localhost.

```
<script>
var host = window.location.hostname;
if(host != "localhost")
{
    // your google analytic code here
}
</script>
```